# Blocking navigation with preventDefault() doesn't work on angularjs $locationChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, preventdefault

I am trying to block user to navigate to other pages when they have unsaved changes on the existing page. 
I use $locationChangeStart and try to trigger a pop-up message to ask user if they really want to navigate without saving the changes.

However, the view changes before even my pop-up gets triggered.
Simply my event.preventDefault() doesn't work.
Not sure what I am doing wrong, but here is the code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
        var path = $location.path();
        if (self.editCableMode || self.editBinMode) {
            SweetAlert.swal({
                title: 'Still Editing',
                text: 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave?',
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#F8BB86',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    console.log(isConfirm)
                    self.editCableMode = false;
                    self.editBinMode = false;
                }else{
                    console.log(isConfirm)

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: The `preventDefault()` needs to be executed immediately, not asynchronously from a callback.

Comment: I tried it, but it still changes the location, I cant get it prevent from directing to next URL, it doesnt stop.
Where do you think should I put event.preventDefault() ? 
I tried putting it in the first line within the function, but still no change...